# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.0.v20130308

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jetty

While trying to compile project via maven install am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project <ProjectName>: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project <projectName>.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to 
collect dependencies at org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.0.v20130308:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jettyserver:jar:9.0.0.v20130308: 
Could not transfer artifact org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:pom:9.0.0.v20130308 
from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: What is your settings.xml? Try doing Maven->Update Project-> Check Force Update ->Finish

Comment: @Anirudh May I know how can I edit settings.xml so that it could download jars from intranet

Comment: You should be able to find the settings.xml in Workspace directory/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: `org.eclipse.jetty:jettyserver:jar:9.0.0.v20130308` is invalid. that should be `jetty-server` (with the dash).   Also, Jetty 9.0.0 is **very** old and out of date, consider using something recent and stable. (such as Jetty `9.4.8.v20171121`)